# Гетеры и сеттеры C++

Tags: c++, классы

Можете объяснить, как более правильно написать геттер для этого класса?

```
class Data{
public:
    string famil, name, skype, email, tg, mainlng;
    int lvlprog;

    Data(string _famil="", string _name="",string _skype="", string _email="", string _tg="",string _mainlng="", int _lvlprog=0):famil(_famil),name(_name),skype(_skype),email(_email),tg(_tg),mainlng(_mainlng),lvlprog(_lvlprog) {
    }

    void SetData(string _famil="", string _name="",string _skype="", string _email="", string _tg="",string _mainlng="", int _lvlprog=0) {
        famil =_famil;
        name =_name;
        skype =_skype;
        email =_email;
        tg =_tg;
        mainlng =_mainlng;
        lvlprog =_lvlprog;
    }

    string GetData() {  
    }
};
```

Comment: Для этого правильнее всего не писать ни одного, потому что все поля и так публичные.

Comment: Просто `string getFamil() const { return famil; }`, `string getName() const { return name; }` ...

Comment: @bipll И это тем более верно, что это просто набор данных без каких-то поддерживаемых инвариантов, так что такие классы лучше делать именно структурами. Тут прятать просто нечего :)

Comment: @ffk Или `const string &getFamil() ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Data
{
public:
    Data(std::string _famil = "", std::string _name = "", std::string _skype = "", std::string _email = "", std::string _tg = "", std::string _mainlng = "", int _lvlprog = 0)
        : famil   { _famil }
        , name    { _name }
        , skype   { _skype }
        , email   { _email }
        , tg      { _tg }
        , mainlng { _mainlng }
        , lvlprog { _lvlprog }
    {
    }

    ~Data()
    {
    }

    std::string get_famil() const { return famil; }
    std::string get_name() const { return name; }
    std::string get_skype() const { return skype; }
    std::string get_email() const { return email; }
    std::string get_tg() const { return tg; }
    std::string get_mainlng() const { return mainlng; }
    int get_lvlprog() const { return lvlprog; }

    void set_famil(const std::string& _famil) { famil = _famil; }
    void set_name(const std::string& _name) { name = _name; }
    void set_skype(const std::string& _skype) { skype = _skype; }
    void set_email(const std::string& _email) { email = _email; }
    void set_tg(const std::string& _tg) { tg = _tg; }
    void set_mainlng(const std::string& _mainlng) { mainlng = _mainlng; }
    void set_lvlprog(int _lvlprog) { lvlprog = _lvlprog; }

protected:
    std::string famil;
    std::string name;
    std::string skype;
    std::string email;
    std::string tg;
    std::string mainlng;
    int lvlprog;
};
```

В самом общем случае гет/сет реализуются для каждого конкрентного поля класса.
Если необходимо предоставить весь набор полей класса вызывающей стороне, то определяется формат в котором это надо, например вернем класс как кортеж:

```
std::tuple<std::string, std::string, std::string, std::string, std::string, std::string, int> get_as_tuple() const
    {
        return std::make_tuple(famil, name, skype, email, tg, mainlng, lvlprog);
    }
```

Или вернем класс в виде json строки (код условный)

```
std::string get_as_json() const
{
    JSON_Document document;

    document.add_field("famil", famil);
    document.add_field("name", name);
    document.add_field("skype", skype);
    document.add_field("email", email);
    document.add_field("tg", tg);
    document.add_field("mainlng", mainlng);
    document.add_field("lvlprog", lvlprog);

    return document.to_std_string();
    // {
    //  "famil": "Pupkin",
    //  "name": "Vasya",
    //  ...
    // }
}
```

Также это может быть мап (ключ-значение), вектор, хмл или любой другой нужный вам формат

Какой конкретно способ выбрать зависит от условий использования. Если данные публичные, то <s>проще</s> лучше организовать вместо класса структуру с публичными полями.

Comment: Если по любому обеспечивается доступ, то зачем их вообше сделать  закрытыми? И структура ничем не проще класса, просто  ею пользуются, чтобы выразить свои намерения  неинкапсулировать данные

Comment: А зхачем вы возвращаете копии? ведь куда проще и эффективнее не `std::string get_famil() const { return famil; }`, а `const std::string& get_famil() const { return famil; }`.

Comment: @Mikhailo, в целом да, но иногда могут получиться битые ссылки

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, согласен, под "проще" имел в виду "лучше". Про намерения из контекста вопроса непонятно :) По мне геттеры лучше, чем паблик-поля, т.к. константный геттер гарантированно не изменяет состояние объекта, а с паблик полями каждый может это сделать. В директХ есть структура DIJOYSTATE2. Например есть поток поллер и массив объектов-трансляторов. Поллер поочередно вызывает метод `translate (const DIJOYSTATE2& state)` каждого транслятора. Если в одном из трансляторов убрать константность state, то можно изменить state и тем самым изменить поведение последующих трансляторов.

Comment: @goldstar_labs, согласен, все зависит от  намерений.  Когда геттер возвращает копию, тут уж точно не дотронешься до приватного члена.  Я бы с вами был полностью согласен, еслибы не сеттеры. Т.е. для всех обьектов есть и геттеры и сеттеры.  Т.е. поля доступны и для чтения и для записи. Так что  конкретно в данном случаи, вычеркивая и геттеры и сеттеры, сделав поля открытыми,  мы выразим те же мысли. Конечно, во многих случаях есть необходимость получать копию приватного члена, но не для данного случая